# Change the image of an picture box from an usercontrol to an form with an imagelink

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the image of a picture box in form2 from an usercontrol that is placed in form1 when I change the value in a combobox. I want the image to stream from an image link like this one "https://i.imgur.com/xxxxxx.png".
This is what I have done yet.

This is form1 with the usercontrol put in it.

```
 private void combobox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newText = combobox.Text;
            Form2 crsF = new Form2();
            if (check_Enabled.Checked)
            {
                switch (newText)
                {
                    case "White":
                        crsF.UpdatePictureBox("https://i.imgur.com/HDuKdEh.png");
                        break;
                    case "Red":
                        crsF.UpdatePictureBox("https://i.imgur.com/HDuKdEh.png");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is form2 that I want to change the image of

```
            public void UpdatePictureBox(string streamLink)
            {
              var request = WebRequest.Create(streamLink);

              using (var response = request.GetResponse())
              using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

I start form2 with this code.

```
Form2 csrF;
        private void combobox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            crsF = new Form2();
            if (combobox.Checked)
            {
                crsF = new CrosshairForm();
                crsF.Show();
            }
            else if (!combobox.Checked)
            {
                Form2 obj = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
                obj.Close();
            }
        }
```

I've tried many different things and I like to solve things myself by I really have spent some time on this function and I just can't manage to get it right, all help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code is creating a “NEW” `Form2` and calling its `UpdatePictureBox` method… however, this form is never shown. `Crsf.Show()` … the picture may change but you will not see it.

Comment: @JohnG how do i do it then? im pretty new to coding in c# thanks for the answer

Comment: This didn't work, the crsF inside the event says "doesnt match this context"

Comment: Can you show the changes you made? [edit] your question with the updated code.

Comment: Updated the question with the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution!

**Form 1**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string Link;

        private void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newText = combobox.Text;
            switch (newText)
            {
                case "White":
                    Link = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/fc/80/7c/fc807ccc8b44a604c276614ed29f5067.jpg";
                    break;
                case "Red":
                    Link = "https://i.imgur.com/HDuKdEh.png";
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void check_Enabled_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Link))
            {
                Form2 crsF = new Form2();
                if (check_Enabled.Checked)
                {
                    crsF.UpdatePictureBox(Link);
                    crsF.Show();
                }
                else if (!check_Enabled.Checked)
                {
                    Form2 obj = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        obj.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Form 2**

```
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WinFormsApp2
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            public void UpdatePictureBox(string streamLink)
            {
                System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(streamLink);
    
                System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
                Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238817/discussion-on-answer-by-ahmed-alayat-change-the-image-of-an-picture-box-from-an).